# How to calculate total time in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, time

I have Project about timesheet, i have tasks table and timers table, each task has many timers and timers belong to task.

I calculated the time between start_at and end_at timer  in getTotalAttribute ,and i got the difference between them in minutes.

**Timer Model**

```
class TsTimer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $appends = ['total'];

    public $casts = [
        'start' => 'datetime',
        'end' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function task(){
        return $this->belongsTo(TsTask::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function getTotalAttribute(){
        // calclute the difference between two time start and end in mints.
        if($this->end){
            return $this->start->diffInMinutes($this->end);
        }     
    return 0;
    }
```

**Task Model**

```
class TsTask extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $appends = ['total', 'timer_total'];

    public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo(TsProject::class);
    }

    public function timers(){
        return $this->hasMany(TsTimer::class,'task_id');
    }

    public function getTotalAttribute(){
        $format=$this->timers->sum('total');
        return date('i:s',$format);
    }
```

And now i need to calculate total time for these timers, like for example first timer (4hours - 10 min), second timer (1 hour), the total will be 5:10.

So i need to calculate this total , any help or suggestion please, i have no idea how to calculate it.

Thanks in advance

Here photo about app:

[App overview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq7zR.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Maybe it's easier to work with `DateTime` or the difference in seconds throughout the application instead of casting it to a formatted string in between?

Comment: @NicoHaase The code working, but i need to calculate total time for all timers as you see in the end of  App overview Image, i need suggestions how to calculate it .

Comment: What have you tried to do that? Where are you stuck? What **exactly** is not working when you sum up all timers?

Comment: @NicoHaase Actually, i need a way or idea how to sum up all timers, that what i ask about it.

Comment: Why not sum them up? As far as I see, each timer returns the duration in minutes through `getTotalAttribute()`, and summing that up should be pretty straightforward

Comment: @NicoHaase Yeah that's right as you saw so i need to sum up all these durations.

Forgive me for that, i'm still beginner . Can you please show me how?

Comment: In my opinion the Timer model should have columns [Start_at, Duration], this way you do not need really calculate Task duration in a complicated way, you just do sum('Duration') for "timers" relation.

Answer (score 1):

try this into your task model

```
public function getTotalAttribute(){

  $totalminutes = 0;
    foreach($this->timers->get() as $timer)
        $startTime = Carbon::parse($timer->start_time);
        $endTime = Carbon::parse($timer->end_time);
        $duration = $endTime->diffInMinutes($startTime);
        $totalminutes += $duration;
    }

    return date('H:i', mktime(0, $totalminutes));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav Rangani  for your answer, but maybe you didn't understand my question correctly.

In my code already calculate totalminutes in getTotalAttribute function for each timer as you can see in App overview Image and in the code.

My question is how to calculate all that totalminutes for all timers in one value call it for example total.